# How to solve this error "array to string conversion in php error"?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this problem and do not know how solve it.
The error is in this line:  `$data = (string) "'".$array->$key."'";`

```
function console_array( $array = null ){

    $jsArray = null;

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        $data = null;

        if (is_int($array->$key)){
            $data = (int) $array->$key;
        } else {
            $data = (string) "'".$array->$key."'";
        }

        $jsArray.= "jsArray['$key'] = $data;";
    }

    echo "<script>var jsArray = new Array(); $jsArray window.console.dir(jsArray);</script>";       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace everywhere `$array->$key` with `$array[$key]`